# Different string encoding results in python and php

Tags: php, python

I have encoded the string in python and, got the expected result. And then I tried the same logic in PHP, but I got different results.
I need to get the expected result (Python result) in PHP.

Please, anyone, help me to get this result. Thanks

Below is my Python code

```
    import hmac
    import base64
    import requests
    import json
    import time



    time='1571373466.733'

    base_url = 'https://www.test.com'
    request_path = '/api/account'
    api_key='f343faf6-70d8-46db-a04d-1142304e3551'
    secret_key= '7C73595142C6CB7A016A7B0D4D6EA24C'
    passphrase= 'tVLd8b2xdoLOKCpc2adfIKE'
    timestamp=time
    body=''
    method='GET'


    message = str(timestamp) + str.upper(method) + request_path + str(body)

    mac = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
    d = mac.digest()

    print(base64.b64encode(d)) # I want to get this same result in PHP
    # result is : b'+Ek2Tel8H0GxWELhNnI/MdsQI4+GpLzZWHAkjzh/NFI='
```

My PHP Code is below

```
    <?php
    $endpoint='https://www.test.com';
    $request_path ='/api/account';
    $api_key='f343faf6-70d8-46db-a04d-1142304e3551';
    $secret_key= '7C73595142C6CB7A016A7B0D4D6EA24C';
    $passphrase= 'tVLd8b2xdoLOKCpc2adfIKE';
    $timestamp='1571373466.733';
    $body='';
    $method='GET';


    $sign=$timestamp.$method.$request_path.$body;
    $sign = utf8_encode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', utf8_encode($sign), utf8_encode($secret_key))));
    print_r($sign);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP code you are missing an argument to ask for raw output. See the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php).

You need to add `$raw_output=true` to your `hash_hmac` call as in:

```
hash_hmac('sha256', utf8_encode($sign), utf8_encode($secret_key), , $raw_output=true)
```